# recuperate the value in the view from controller

Tags: apex

plz 
I have a  probeleme to recuperate the value in the view, my fields are the good values in the controller but I do not recuperate the value in view .
no value in the variable      '{!soql}'

vue :

```
function fillText()
   { 

       validate_MACAdress_Format();;
       alert(" return value from Validation : " + '{!soql}')
   }
```

....

```
  apex:actionFunction name="validate_MACAdress" action="{!validate_MACAdress}" reRender="hi">
   apex:param name="valMAC_Adress" value=""/>
   /apex:actionFunction>
```

...

```
   <td><apex:outputLabel value="MAC Address:" style="everythingOnOneLine" /></td>    
   <td><apex:inputText id="inputMACAddress"    value="{!inputMACAddress}" onblur="fillText();" /></td>
```

controller :

```
public boolean soql {get;set;}

    public PageReference validate_MACAdress_Format()
    {        
       soql = Model_OlympusLR_Utility.validateMACFormat(inputMACAddress);
       return null;
    }
```

Model :

```
//VALIDATE MAC ADDRESS FORMAT a-f,A-F,0-9 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
public static boolean validateMACFormat(String inputMACAddress)
{        
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile('^([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9][:]){5}[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]$');
     Matcher m = p.matcher(inputMACAddress);
     return m.find();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Script Function to

```
function fillText(mac) {

   validate_MACAdress_Format(mac);;

}
```

Change td to

```
<td><apex:inputText id="inputMACAddress"    value="{!inputMACAddress}" onblur="fillText(this.value);" /></td>
```

If you want to output the value then you will have to use an output panel and rerender it. The value of {!soql} will not refresh in the function when it is updated in the controller

Something like

```
apex:actionFunction name="validate_MACAdress" action="{!validate_MACAdress}" reRender="result">
             apex:param name="valMAC_Adress" value=""/> 
</apex:actionFunction>
```

this on the page

```
<apex:outPutPanel layout="block" id="result">
  <apex:outPutText value="{!soql}"/>
</apex:outPutPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

but the program will not accept the value

< apex: outputText value = "{SOQL!}" />

Comment: Because you typed it wrong......

Comment: plz what's worong?

Comment: @muzin the syntax to bind variables in Visualforce is `{! ..  }`  , you have wrote  `{ .. !}`

Comment: I m sorry,in my program that's a good syntaxe but dont work < apex:outPutText value='{!soql}'/>